# Reusing streams of data for some time

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

Let's say one has an API that accepts queries and returns streams of results, as some of results can change.

```
type Query = { 
  species?: "dog" | "cat" | "rat", 
  name?: "string",
  status?: "lost" | "found"
}
type Result = { species: string, name: string, status: string }[]
```

Let's say there are multiple components passing queries to this API and some of them might be the same. One does not want to send needless requests to server and likes to optimize - in order to do this API can be wrapped and calls intercepted.

```
interface ServiceApi {
  request(query: Query): Observable<Result>
}

class WrappedServiceApi implements ServiceApi {
  constructor(private service: ServiceApi) { }

  request(query: Query): Observable<Result> {
    // intercepted
    return this.service.request(query);
  }
}
```

**But how to approach this kind optimization using RxJS 5?**

Doing it around RxJS might look similar to this:

```
class WrappedServiceApi implements ServiceApi {

  private activeQueries;
  constructor(private service: ServiceApi) { 
    this.activeQueries = new Map<string, Observable<Result>>();
  }

  request(query: Query): Observable<Result> {
    // it's easy to stringify query
    const hashed: string = hash(query);
    if (this.activeQueries.has(hashed)) {
      // reuse existing stream
      return this.activeQueries.get(hashed);
    } else {
      // create multicast stream that remembers last value
      const results = this.service.request(query).publishLast();
      // store stream for reuse
      this.activeQueries.set(hashed, results);
      // delete stream 5s after it closed
      results.toPromise().then(
        () => setTimeout(
          () => this.activeQueries.delete(hashed), 
          5000
        )
      );
      return results;
    }
  }
}
```

Can the same be achieved in more declarative rx-way?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but I'd do it like this:

```
request(query: Query): Observable<Result> {
    return Observable.of(hash(query))
        .flatMap(hashed => {
            const activeQueries = this.activeQueries;
            if (activeQueries.has(hashed)) {
                return activeQueries.get(hashed);
            } else {
                const obs = this.service.request(query)
                    .publishReplay(1, 5000)
                    .refCount()
                    .take(1);

                activeQueries.set(hashed, obs);
                return obs;
            }
        });
}
```

Basically the only difference is that I'm storing Observables in the `this.activeQueries` instead of just their results and then I cache them for 5s using `.publishReplay(1, 5000)`. This way when you subscribe to the same Observable after 5s it'll just resubscribe to its source Observable.

Comment: Unless you do a flatMap it returns higher order stream, so breaks the contract. Original examples also stored observables (however publishReplay is better that publishLast) in activeQueries. Documentation link suggests using Rx.Obervable.defer and stream factory, to make sure the calls to API are actually made.

Comment: It would be nice to get rid of this activeQueries map too, though.

Comment: True, there should be `flatMap`